# Javascript Optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to figure out how to get this `JS` to work. The `scroll` `function` works but not the hide. Also is there anyway to do this with less lines of code? I want `.down-arrow` to `fade out` after `50px` and hide after the `50px` that way it can't be clicked on. It was working on my site and codepen, but then it randomly stopped working. The code is clearly wrong, but somehow it was working...

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".down-arrow").css("opacity", 1 -
    $(window).scrollTop() / 50 );
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".down-arrow").hide(fast);
   $(window).scrollTop() > 50 );
});
```

[Edit]

Here is the new JS I wrote with advice on the obvious syntax error and suggestions to place it all in one body, which I was hoping to do anyways:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".down-arrow").hide("fast");
    $(".down-arrow").css("opacity", 1 -
      $(window).scrollTop() / 50 );
});
```

But now I want the arrow to show when the use goes back up to the top, above the 50px mark.

Comment: Maybe because it's a syntax error?

Comment: *"Also is there anyway to do this with less lines of code?"* - There is no need to define two separate scroll handlers, just put the bodies of both of those functions into a single function inside a single call to `$(window).scroll()`.

Comment: Yes lol @bergi but it is more than that.

Comment: I was hoping to do that but couldn't get anything to work so I had to figure out how to do it in two seperate bodies. Thanks, I will do that!

Comment: Got it working, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of's first, there is no need to register a funcition twice

```
var element = $(".down-arrow");
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(window).scrollTop() > 50){
   element.css("opacity","0");
   if(!element.hasClass("hidden")){
     element.addClass("hidden");
   }
   }else{
   $('.down-arrow').removeClass("hidden") // if there is nothing, nothing to remove
   $(".down-arrow").css("opacity", 1 -$(window).scrollTop() / 50 );
   }
});
```

Some CSS change :

```
.down-arrow.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.down-arrow:hover {
  //you have to overwrite inline opacity , which js makes..
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Now it should work as expected, try :)

Comment: I am doing this on a link so just changing the opacity does not work, it has to be hidden. Otherwise it is still clickable.

Comment: Here you cans see it in action. It seems like the opacity is lowered even when you are at the top of the page? [link] (http://codepen.io/ericshio/pen/zBRbAY)

Comment: Yep, I'm currently trying to fix that. :)

Comment: Cheers! :) Thank you so much for your help! I have been trying to figure this out for weeks! :P

Comment: I changed the opacity 1 - to 0.6 - because that is what the css is set for when the img is not being hovered over.

Comment: fade out after 50px and hide after the 50px that way it can't be clicked on ,  when you scroll down 50 px it will hide ? don't get you, isn't that what you wanted? or you want it when user scrolls to end of your page

Comment: Sorry, changed some of the css on my site and it works perfectly, not sure what happened! Everything is working exactly as intended!